# php if-statement based on integers is not displaying results?

Tags: php, switch-statement

I'm using the following `preg_match`:

```
preg_match( '!<div class="thumblock ">(.*)</div>!si' , wp_gdsr_render_article_thumbs(0, false, "", 0, "", false) , $n );
$thumbs_string = strip_tags( $n[1] );
```

To extract the number between the span tags:

```
<div class="thumblock ">
<span class="rating-result">
<div id="gdsr_thumb_text_12_a" class="gdt-size-20 voted inactive gdthumbtext">+1</div>
</span>
<div class="ratingtext ">
<div class="raterclear"></div>
</div>
```

(in the example above, result is a string: "+1")

So I tried converting it into an integer with this:

`$thumbs_number = (int)$thumbs_string;`

which is used in this function:

```
function get_rating_class($thumbs_number) {
    if ($thumbs_number < 0) return ' bad';
    if ($thumbs_number < 2) return ' average';
    if ($thumbs_number < 4) return ' good';
    return ' excellent';
}

function rating_class($thumbs_number) {
    echo get_rating_class($thumbs_number);
}
```

to output a div class:

```
<div class="topic-like-count<?php rating_class($thumbs_number); ?>">
```

I even did `var_dump()`:

```
<h2><?php var_dump($thumbs_string); ?></h2>
<h2><?php var_dump($thumbs_number); ?></h2>
```

and the results were:

`string(2) "+1"` and `int(1)` respectively (I directly copy/pasted them here).

But no div class is being output.

Any suggestion to fix this?

**EDIT:**

The class is indeed being output in the HTML source, but it isn't having any effect (and my stylesheet is not being cached). I have another version of the function which doesn't add an extra div around the span tags, and that one works but unfortunately I need that div.

Comment: Where is the switch statement?

Comment: @cdhowie Sorry it used to be a switch statement, now it is an if statement.

Comment: Are you positive that the class is not in the HTML source?  (Have you done a CTRL+F5 to purge the cache in case an old version of your stylesheet is being cached?)

Comment: If the class name is being written, then **the PHP code is fine**.  There is a problem with your stylesheet; fix it.

Comment: @cdhowie Damn, stupid me, you were right, because of the extra div my css had to be modified. Can you post a answer so that I can tick it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the class name is being displayed in the HTML then the PHP code is fine.  The stylesheet is likely the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Sure.. add an `echo` before the call to `rating_class($thumbs_number);`:

```
<div class="topic-like-count<?php echo rating_class($thumbs_number); ?>">
```

Comment: There is an `echo` statement inside the `rating_class()` function.  `rating_class()` has no return value, and echoing it will likely issue a PHP notice.

Comment: Right, didn't see it! Echoing wouldn't raise a notice though, it's allowed to echo a NULL value

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using an extra function that's only used to echo? The following should work just fine.

```
<div class="topic-like-count<?=get_rating_class($thumbs_number);?>">
```

Comment: I don't think that's the problem. I'm already echoing the function.

Comment: Have you tried any of the suggestions given before saying you don't think that's the issue? You may be surprised to find that they do actually work.